# Using XSLT to add an attribute, then using that new attribute to sort

Tags: xslt, sorting

I am familiar with the basics of XSLT, but I've hit a weird situation I can't seem to figure out.  I apologize for this being so long, but I would really appreciate any help you could provide.

I'm using a transformation on XML produced by a software product that I don't have control over.  The product exports data that looks something like this:

```
<header>
   <data>
   </data>
</header>
<transaction>
    <B1_PG1 ts='1139977698718.75'><data></data></B1_PG1>
    <B1_PG2 ts='1139977698718.76'><data></data></B1_PG2>
    <B2_PG1 ts='1139977698718.77'><data></data></B2_PG1>
    <B2_PG2 ts='1139977698718.78'><data></data></B2_PG2>
    <B2_PG1 ts='1139977698718.79'><data></data></B2_PG1>
    <B2_PG2 ts='1139977698718.80'><data></data></B2_PG2>
    <B3_PG1 ts='1139977698718.81'><data></data></B3_PG1>
</transaction>
```

where the software product is exporting pages of data, in the order that it receives them.  I need to take those pages and sort them in a custom order for processing into another system. So, I created a lookup document that looks something like this to define my custom sort order:

(PageSequences.xml)

```
<pages>
    <page id="B2_PG1" sequence="1000" />
    <page id="B2_PG2" sequence="1010" />
    <page id="B3_PG1" sequence="2000" />
    <page id="B1_PG1" sequence="3000" />
    <page id="B1_PG2" sequence="3010" />
</pages>
```

I then lookup that sequence based on the element name, concatenate that with the timestamp, and inject an attribute into the element using the following XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/> 
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/> 
    <xsl:variable name='page-seqs' select='document("PageSequences.xml")/pages/page'/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*"> 
        <xsl:copy> 
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()">
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy> 
    </xsl:template> 

    <xsl:template match="transaction">
        <transaction>

            <xsl:for-each select="child::node()">
                <xsl:variable name='localname' select='local-name()'/>
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:attribute name="sequence">
                        <xsl:value-of select='$page-seqs[@id=$localname]/@sequence'/>-<xsl:value-of select='@ts'/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()">
                        <xsl:sort select="@sequence" />
                    </xsl:apply-templates>
                </xsl:copy> 
            </xsl:for-each>
        </transaction>
        </xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The problem I am running into is that the  tag doesn't seem to be working.  I would expect the following:

```
<transaction>
    <B2_PG1 ts='1139977698718.77' sequence='1000-1139977698718.77'><data></data></B2_PG1>
    <B2_PG1 ts='1139977698718.79' sequence='1000-1139977698718.79'><data></data></B2_PG1>
    <B2_PG2 ts='1139977698718.78' sequence='1010-1139977698718.78'><data></data></B2_PG2>
    <B2_PG2 ts='1139977698718.80' sequence='1010-1139977698718.80'><data></data></B2_PG2>
    <B3_PG1 ts='1139977698718.81' sequence='2000-1139977698718.81'><data></data></B3_PG1>
    <B1_PG1 ts='1139977698718.75' sequence='3000-1139977698718.75'><data></data></B1_PG1>
    <B1_PG2 ts='1139977698718.76' sequence='3010-1139977698718.76'><data></data></B1_PG2>
</transaction>
```

but I'm getting:

```
<transaction>
    <B1_PG1 ts='1139977698718.75' sequence='3000-1139977698718.75'><data></data></B1_PG1>
    <B1_PG2 ts='1139977698718.76' sequence='3010-1139977698718.76'><data></data></B1_PG2>
    <B2_PG1 ts='1139977698718.77' sequence='1000-1139977698718.77'><data></data></B2_PG1>
    <B2_PG2 ts='1139977698718.78' sequence='1010-1139977698718.78'><data></data></B2_PG2>
    <B2_PG1 ts='1139977698718.79' sequence='1000-1139977698718.79'><data></data></B2_PG1>
    <B2_PG2 ts='1139977698718.80' sequence='1010-1139977698718.80'><data></data></B2_PG2>
    <B3_PG1 ts='1139977698718.81' sequence='2000-1139977698718.81'><data></data></B3_PG1>
</transaction>
```

In addition, please let me know if you think I'm approaching this in the wrong way.  I'm trying to avoid using java/c#/perl/etc... to keep the transformation as portable as possible.  I'd also like to avoid performing two transformations for performance reasons.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you have is within this block of code

```
<xsl:copy> 
   <xsl:attribute name="sequence"> 
      <xsl:value-of select='$page-seqs[@id=$localname]/@sequence'/>-<xsl:value-of select='@ts'/> 
   </xsl:attribute> 
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"> 
      <xsl:sort select="@sequence" /> 
   </xsl:apply-templates> 
</xsl:copy>
```

In particular, the apply-templates. Firstly, at this stage you have already copied and output the "B-PG" element, and all the apply-templates is doing is processing its child nodes. Secondly, the sort would only work on the input document, and not any extra attributes you have added to the output document.

What you could do then, is put the results of your copying the transaction child nodes into a variable, and then iterate over that variable with a sort. This would be a 'two-pass transformation' within the same XSLT document. However, in this case, it is not necessary. You can just simply match all the transaction child nodes, and specify the look-up of the sequence numbers in the sort

```
<xsl:sort select="$page-seqs[@id=local-name(current())]/@sequence" />
```

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

   <xsl:variable name="page-seqs" select="document('C:\lookup.xml')/pages/page"/>

   <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="transaction">
      <transaction>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="child::node()">
            <xsl:sort select="$page-seqs[@id=local-name(current())]/@sequence"/>
         </xsl:apply-templates>
      </transaction>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your sample document (minus the **header** element, because currently the XML sample is not well formed), the following is output

```
<transaction>
   <B2_PG1 ts="1139977698718.77">
      <data/>
   </B2_PG1>
   <B2_PG1 ts="1139977698718.79">
      <data/>
   </B2_PG1>
   <B2_PG2 ts="1139977698718.78">
      <data/>
   </B2_PG2>
   <B2_PG2 ts="1139977698718.80">
      <data/>
   </B2_PG2>
   <B3_PG1 ts="1139977698718.81">
      <data/>
   </B3_PG1>
   <B1_PG1 ts="1139977698718.75">
      <data/>
   </B1_PG1>
   <B1_PG2 ts="1139977698718.76">
      <data/>
   </B1_PG2>
</transaction>
```

Do note that it is preferably to use apply-templates over for-each, which is what I have done here.

Comment: This is perfect Tim, thanks much.  It allows me to perform the sort without the pass required to add the attribute.  It would allow a custom sort against any element.

Answer (score 1):

The attribute that you created is present on the newly constructed elements that you are placing on the result tree, but it is not present on the elements from the source tree that you are sorting.

The other problem is that you are not sorting the children of the transaction element, but its grandchildren.

I suspect what you want is this:

```
           <xsl:for-each select="child::node()">
              <xsl:sort select="concat($page-seqs[@id=local-name(current())]/@sequence, '-', @ts)"/>
                <xsl:variable name='localname' select='local-name()'/>
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:attribute name="sequence">
                        <xsl:value-of select='$page-seqs[@id=$localname]/@sequence'/>-<xsl:value-of select='@ts'/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
                </xsl:copy> 
            </xsl:for-each>
```

The only way to avoid repeating the computation (once in the xsl:sort, once to produce the output attribute) is to do two passes, one to add the attribute, the next to sort on it. The way of doing that varies between XSLT 1.0 and 2.0, and you didn't say which you were using. The two pass approach is quite feasible, but in your case I suspect the single pass with the repeated computation is more efficient (though you'll have to measure both to find out).

Comment: Michael, I appreciate you trying to make my less than average XSLT idea work, this would have done it too.